# how to use a variable in requests library of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, python-requests

I'm trying to make a script which reads crunchyroll's rss and visits the LINK in the latest upload and downloads subs from it..
the process goes like :
1.) Read The latest episode link from RSS.
2.) Go to the link
3.) In the source code, look for text "ssid".
4.) Get the 6 characters of the ssid.
5.) Then append those characters at the end of this like "http://www.crunchyroll.com/xml/?req=RpcApiSubtitle_GetXml&subtitle_script_id=" and save the xml page.

My script works half way...

My Code:-

```
import feedparser
import webbrowser
import os
import subprocess  
import re
import urllib
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import cookielib


feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.crunchyroll.com/rss/anime')  #checks the RSS
url = feed['entries'][0]['link'] + '?p720=1'         # get's the link from latest release and appends some character for the 720p resolution of the link.

# Now, here, I'm writing this URL to a text file and then read from the text file

file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
file.write(url)
file.close()

file = open('newfile.txt', 'r')
#print file.read()
lobo = file.read()
print lobo

# Now, I put the URL that is being read from file in requests to go to the link. Everything works fine till here.

r = requests.get(lobo)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup.title
webbrowser.open_new_tab(lobo)
subtitles = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'showmedia-subtitle-text'})
for ssid in subtitles:
  x = ssid.find_all('a', limit=1)
for a in x:
  print a['href'][-6:]

xmlLink = 'http://www.crunchyroll.com/xml/?req=RpcApiSubtitle_GetXml&subtitle_script_id=' + a['href'][-6:]
#webbrowser.open_new_tab(xmlLink)
print xmlLink
```

Now, I get error that 'a' in this xmlLink is not defined.

But, there's a twist to it... if I put the direct http link in "r = requests.get(lobo)" .. everything works like it is supposed to.But, if I use this variable.. it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `a` variable is defined inside of the `for` loop but the `xmlLink` variable is not. Try indenting the `xmlLink` line in to match the indentation level of the `for` loop. For example:

```
for a in x:
  print a['href'][-6:]

  xmlLink = 'http://www.crunchyroll.com/xml/?req=RpcApiSubtitle_GetXml&subtitle_script_id=' + a['href'][-6:]
  #webbrowser.open_new_tab(xmlLink)
  print xmlLink
```

Comment: well, it removed the error, but, the problem is that the value of ssid isn't being parsed in the link at end... no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

The url that you're using is a `str`. You should use Python's string format function.

```
xmlLinkBase = 'http://www.crunchyroll.com/xml/?req=RpcApiSubtitle_GetXml&subtitle_script_id={0}'
for a in x:
   print a['href'][-6:]
   xmlLink =  xmlLinkBase.format(a['href'][-6:])
   #webbrowser.open_new_tab(xmlLink)
   print xmlLink
```

`str.format` [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format)